# In the Harry Potter Lego Years 1-4 for iPad (IOS) what are the two hidden challenges?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

For the IOS Version of this game, there are 34 achievements which are listed in the Game Center. Two of those are hidden challenges. I found out what one of them was, which is called Silence Please! and I completed it but no one seems to know what the other one is.

Would be very grateful if you could help because it has been bothering me for some time now and I would love to have achieved everything in the game! Thank you!

Comment: I found an [achievement guide](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/achievements-guide), but it doesn't say which ones are hidden or not.  Maybe you could compare the list to the ones you have to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

The second is getting past the prefects without being detected on pursuing pettigrew