# What is the hidden achievement that I'm missing for LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4 iOS?

Tags: achievements, ios, lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I'm having trouble working out how to complete the achievement list on my LEGO Harry Potter game iOS. I've got all achievements except for one but it's a hidden achievement; so I'm unable to work out what it is, and how to finish it.

The achievements I've completed are called:

- Junior
- Senior
- Prefect
- Head Boy
- Teacher's Pet
- Story Complete!
- Hat Collector
- Hat Fanatic
- Ultra Collector
- Ultimate Collector
- Supreme Collector
- Power Up!
- Stud Magnet
- You're the Best
- Dark Wizards
- Quidditch Team
- Back in Time
- Wonderful Weasleys
- Quirrell Quandary
- Multiplier
- Arachnophobe
- Animagus
- Defeating the Object
- Voldemort's Defeat
- Quick Quidditch
- Cultured
- A People Person
- Troll Perfected
- Basilisk Perfected
- Whomping Willow Perfected
- Dragon Perfected
- You Can't See Me!
- Billionaire's Club

Does anyone know what the final achievement is and how to earn it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the Harry Potter Lego Years 1-4 for iPad (IOS) what are the two hidden challenges?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265185/in-the-harry-potter-lego-years-1-4-for-ipad-ios-what-are-the-two-hidden-challe)

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be two hidden achievements out of 34 total. You've already completed one as 33/34 achievements are listed above, so your remaining challenge will be either:

- "Quiet, please", which solution can be found [here](https://www.supercheats.com/iphoneipad/questions/legoharrypotteryears14/301648/i-m-playing-the-ios-version-an.htm)
- Avoiding the prefects on year 3, as in [holly's very similar topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265185/in-the-harry-potter-lego-years-1-4-for-ipad-ios-what-are-the-two-hidden-challe) here

In both cases, all achievements were listed and described on [supercheat](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/achievements-guide)